# Android video is rotated when play from web server

Tags: android, android-video-player, android-videoview

I'm playing video from web server, the video is playing on videoview nicely, but some samsung mobile playing the video on 90 degree rotation. But the same video playing without ration on others devices.

```
public void playVideo(String videoPath) {
    try {
        vidFull.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                        switch (what) {
                            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START:
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                break;
                            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END:
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(vidFull);
        vidFull.setMediaController(mediaController);
        vidFull.setVideoPath(videoPath);
        vidFull.requestFocus();
        vidFull.start();
        videoArrayLength = videoArrayLength -1;
        vidpointer = 1;
        //Goutam 17.03.2016

        vidFull.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                logCollection.setLogERed(""+videoArrayLength);
                try {
                    if (videoArrayLength > 0){
                        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(FullPost.this);
                        mediaController.setAnchorView(vidFull);
                        vidFull.setMediaController(mediaController);
                        //vidFull.setVideoPath("http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/480/big_buck_bunny_480p_1mb.mp4");
                        logCollection.setLogERed(basevideourl+videoArray.optJSONObject(vidpointer).getString("vdLink"));
                        vidFull.setVideoPath(basevideourl + videoArray.optJSONObject(vidpointer).getString("vdLink"));
                        vidFull.requestFocus();
                        vidFull.start();
                        videoArrayLength = videoArrayLength - 1;
                        vidpointer = vidpointer + 1;
                       }else {
                        logCollection.showToastLong("No more video to play.");
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error connecting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you telling about orientation change. You can handle this by setting **screenOrientation** to activity in AndroidManifest.

```
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
```

Comment: Activity is portrait in manifest, it's not an issue, when playing videoview and all are in portrait mode, but only video is rotated in some samsung phone.